# How do I export runtime datatable into excel if any error occurs due to data?

Tags: excel, hp-uft, vba

I want to know if I can export a datatable into excel when I get an error due to data while running the scripts.

If i am having 5 records in a sheet, and 2 records processed well, while running the third record my script encounters an error. Am I able to export into excel in that moment?

Errors may occur at any places because of the data.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking. Instead of waiting for answers that shoot into the dark by saying "if you mean X, then A, if you mean Y, then B", please post more info, like a script that indicates why you seem to believe there would be a problem. (What is the question: How to export? How to detect errors? Which kind of errors? During what exact operation? Caused by what? What sheet? What data? What error? In short: WHAT?)

Answer (score 1):

*Your question doesn't explicitly say QTP, but I'm assuming QTP because you used the tag HP-UFT.*

I'm not sure what you mean by "when we get error", so I'll explore two possibilites.

1) You're getting an error in the application you are testing; QTP itself is still executing the script.

In this situation, your script should have validation checks (if statements that check to make sure that what you expected to happen did indeed just happen), and if those checks fail, you could immediately do a DataTable.Export(filename) to save the data to disk before QTP ends.  Then, the script could continue, or you can add an ExitTest to fail out and stop the test.

Based on your question, I think it's more likely that:

2) You're getting an error in QTP itself.  When QTP crashes, it drops any dynamic changes to the DataTable (i.e. if you had done a DataTable.Import(filename) or updated any fields, it would loose that and go back to it's design time DataTable instead)

In this situation, your script is encountering something that is causing QTP itself to stop the script.  Perhaps it's hitting an error where an object cannot be found, or some kind of syntax error.  You should consider adding defensive statements to check on things before your code reaches the point that this kind of error would occur... For example, perhaps add...

```
If not Browser("ie").Page("page").WebTable("table").Exists then 
  FailTestBecause "Can't find table" 
End If
```

...

```
function FailTestBecause (reason)
  Print "Test Failed Because: " & reason
  Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, Environment("ActionName"), reason
  DataTable.Export(filename)
  ExitTest
end Function
```

Or, you could just use an On Error Resume Next and put in a command to DataTable.Export(filename) immediately after where it is failing...